# Visual Studio (C++) - Documentation viewer on hover over and function select?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently switching from `Eclipse (Java)` to `Visual Studio (C++)` and I'm missing some functionality.

One of these things is the handy instantaneous Java Doc on hover over, function/class select and while writing code. Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

In Visual Studio, that documentation is pretty much non-existent in the IDE. Sometimes there is also a link to the Bing search engine, but that is the best it can do:

[image]

Is there some setting or add-on to get something similar in Visual Studio?

Searching online, I only find things about documentation *generators*, but barely anything on documentation *viewers*.

---

UPDATE 2023-05-04: Just tried `Eclipse (C++)` and it seems to have the feature I was looking for. Still no answer to my question about `Visual Studio (C++)` though.

Comment: Visual Studio usually uses XML comments format.

Comment: To document your own code or to get documentation about e.g. objects/methods from the STL?

Comment: Visual Studio [supports both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/doxygen-and-xml-doc-comment-support/) XML and Doxygen comments. This is good for your own code, but the problem is, the Microsoft's C++ Standard Library source code is simply not documented inline. Doxygen and other documentation formats in C++ are not "standard" and perhaps are not so universally accepted or used throughout C++ codebases as Javadoc is in Java codebases.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but interesting nonetheless. [+1]